# VBScript which checks if text file exist and when not create one which contain presetted text

Tags: vbscript, hta

I want to check with a vbscript if the text file: `"C:\Temp\CAD_Kunde.txt"` exists and when not it should create one which contains this text:

```
1
BEHR;B18 SP4;B18 SP7;0
AUDI;B19 SP3;0
BMW;B19 SP3;0
BIT;B18 SP4;B19 SP3;B16 SP9;0
CHRYSLER;B18 SP4;0
CAE_64;B19 SP3;0
CNHTC;B19 SP3;0
DAF;B19 SP3;0
DASSAULT;B18 SP7;B19 SP3;0
DFCV;B19 SP3;0
FORD;B18 SP4;0
FREIGHTL;B19 SP3;0
FUSO;B19 SP3;0
HINO;B19 SP3;0
HONDA;B19 SP3;0
IVECO;B19 SP3;0
MAN;B19 SP3;0
NISSAN;B19 SP3;0
MB;B19 SP3;0
PACCAR;B19 SP3;0
PORSCHE;B19 SP3;0
PORSCHE_HYBRID_DX;B19 SP3;0
PSA;B19 SP3;0
RENAULT;B19 SP3;0
RVI;B18 SP4;0
SCANIA;B19 SP3;0
TELCO;B19 SP3;0
UD_TRUCK;B17 SP4;0
VOLVO_CAR;B18 SP4;0
VOLVO_TRUCK;B19 SP3;0
V5_MM;B18 SP4;0
V5_BM;B19 SP3;0
V5_TEST;B19 SP9;0
VW;B19 SP3;0
```

The text in the text file should be created with the same format.

Edit: Ok i have no the part to check the exist of the file and when not to create it. I need help now to implement in the else condition the part to write to the file.

```
<SCRIPT Language="VBScript"> 
Option Explicit  
Dim oTxtFile  
With (CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"))   
If .FileExists("C:\Temp\Kunde.txt") Then       
Else      
Set oTxtFile = .CreateTextFile("C:\Temp\Kunde.txt")
oTxtFile.Close  
End If  
End With
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please look [here](http://www.google.nl/search?q=vbscript+fileexists) and [here](http://www.google.nl/search?q=vbscript+create+text+file) for a quick start.

--- After askers edit ---

Ah, now we are getting somewhere. On Stack Overflow, we expect some effort of the questionair instead of "Can you write me my code?" questions.

After checking if the file does not exists, it would be easier if you open a textfile in ForWriting mode and the Create option to True:

```
dim filesys, filetxt
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8 
Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set filetxt = filesys.OpenTextFile("c:\somefile.txt", ForAppending, True) 
filetxt.WriteLine("Your text goes here.")
filetxt.Close
```

This will create and write text to a textfile.
Now we have to fill it with your text. It would be the easiest if you open excel and copy-paste your text in column B, then:

1. add the following text in cell A1: `filetxt.WriteLine("`
2. add the following text in cell C1: `")`
3. type this formula in column D1: `=A1 & B1 & C1`
4. Copy paste cell A1, C1 and D1 downward to the last filled cell on the B column
5. Copy paste the text in column D to your script where `filetext.WriteLine("Your text goes here.")` is stated.

And run your script.

Final Solution:

```
Option Explicit   
dim filesys, filetxt
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8 
Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If not filesys.FileExists("C:\Temp\Kunde.txt") Then
    Set filetxt = filesys.OpenTextFile("C:\Temp\Kunde.txt", ForWriting, True) 
    ' 
    ' Copy - Paste the appropriate filetext.WriteLine statements here
    '        
    filetxt.Close
End If
```

Comment: your post is not helpful i have edited my own post. when you know vbscript please have a look on my edit.

Comment: Your script works fine but i used `ForWriting`. Now it overwrites any time the file. How can i first let it check if the file exist and when it exist do nothing, but when it not exist create file with text?

Comment: You already created that yourself! But I will help you by editing my former post. And don't forget to accept this as 'The correct answer' as it helped you out ;).